# Draw Transparent Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, ondraw

I have been facing a weird problem in the last 2-3 days. The thing I would like to do looks easy but my solutions do not respond in somehow I would like. Let me inform you about what I certainly want.

I have a picture(.png). I have split it in 5 parts and saved them as .png also. My expectation is to have a view objects displaying those 5 pictures as a picture. So I have decided to use canvas.drawBitmap() method to draw that 5 pics in onDraw() method. It works fine. However, when I wanted to resize it I have used createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, boolean). I have applied this way to every 5 differen bitmap object to resize and draw in onDraw() method. Unfortunately, I have got a full picture but between every picture there was a line vercitally. I have changed the boolean value as true in the method createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, boolean) then it was working well with a bad quality of the picture.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                getResources().getIdentifier(
                        "f" + i, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()));
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, new Matrix(), null);
    }
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/96553428.png

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/33612864.png

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/255/53597408.png

Note : Drawing speed matters. It means it should take less than 500 ms to draw.

Comment: @Simon you can find it from the second image link :)

Comment: Please post it into your question.  It makes is much easier for people to help you.

Comment: You may have better luck just using an `ImageView`.